# Status Bar text Color

Tags: ios, statusbar

As it is shown in the attached figure, status bar text is black. Is there way to change to another color, for example white ?

[image]

Comment: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/

Comment: yes you can change by going in your project target -> General -> then you can see option to change your status bar text colour to white

Answer (score 1):

In your app's plist (or through XCode's GUI) set Status bar style to "Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5)" and you'll get white text. Here's a source for more:

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Answer (score 0):

I have got the following answer which works very well.

Just two steps as following:

Step 1:

Under the Info tab of the project target, Add Row:

```
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance, set value NO.
```

Step 2:

In the project AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    …
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    …
}
```